# HttpClient issue on .net 5.0 and .net 6.0 on localhost

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, .net-core, localhost

I having a ssl certificate error on localhost using httpclient , see error below.
URL used on the httpclient below works fine on the browser.
httpclient using code below works fine on  .net 2.1 core and not on .net 5.0 or.net 6.0.
The SSL certificate was generated using iis express dialog from visual studio (2022)
I run this command : dotnet dev-certs https --trust

Any help is appreciated, thank you

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var url = Url.ActionLink("");
using var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
> remote host. Unknown location
>
> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An
> existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket+AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see
> inner exception.
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
> sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, bool async, Stream stream,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Why do you think it is an TLS issue?  The error says "while processing the request".  TLS is performed before the request is sent.  The request will never be sent if TLS fails. The error is occurring after the connection completes ("while processing").  The default http headers are different inside Net than other browsers.  Most likely you are missing a header or the header as wrong parameters.

Comment: Thank you for you response, the same app works on another machine. It is not a  code issue.

Comment: That is not an acceptable reason to say the it is TLS.  The code could be calling an application that is installed on working machine and not installing on machine that fails.  The code is failing after the connection completes which mean it is not TLS.

Comment: I think I found the issue, there is a proxy setting on the machine and for some reason :option to by pass proxy server for local addresses is not longer working. I am temporarely adding :

var proxyHttpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
      UseProxy = false,
};

Comment: Not the first time I've seen proxy issues like this.  I suggested this morning at anther posting the it may be a proxy issue.  Your exception says connection was forcibly closed which is usually the TCP connection (not TLS).  I suspect the proxy was trying to connect use HTTP instead of HTTS and the server was set to use HTTPS only.